# Ferries in January in the Azores

Tags: ferries, azores

I will arrive on Sao Miguel in the first week January. Form there I actually planed to take a ferry to Pico and further to Flores but I cannot find any information about ferries in January.

Is there anyone who has precise information about ferries in January at the Azores?

Comment: Haven't confirmed it, but [this site](http://www.azores.com/ferry) says there are no ferries between the 3 island groups except during May through September (due to weather).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are out of luck and would have to take a flight instead.

There's two ferry companies in the Azores but only one, [Atlânticoline](https://www.atlanticoline.pt/p/p/), services Sao Miguel and it's [well](http://www.azores.com/ferry) [documented](http://www.ferrylines.com/en/news/artikel/transmacor-opens-new-azores-inter-island-links/) that it only does so between May and September.

I also checked their website for [the January schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiBrN.png) and consistent with the other reports it only showed a shuttle link between Corvo and Flores.